# Почему меню в Materialize CSS не скроллится в мобильных версиях?

Tags: прокрутка, material-design, materialize-css

Заходил со своего iphone 4 на страницу сайта, там мобильное меню от Materialize, но пункты не прокручиваются, когда я пытаюсь пальцем вверх и вниз листать, меню так и остается фиксированным (хотя на десктопе работает)

Заходил на оф. сайт со своего телефона, их меню также не скролится пальцем, что делать?

Comment: Старые системы iOS не поддерживают такой код.

Comment: а есть какой-нибудь полифилл? и можно ли такой написать?

Comment: и нет же, открыл на ipad mini (iOS 10), там тоже не скроллится

Comment: включите overflow для мобильных устройств для использования штатного скролла

Comment: для .side-nav {overflow: scroll} прописал, все равно не работает